# Hive: merge or tag multiple rows based on neighboring rows

Tags: hive

I have the following table and want to merge multiple rows based on neighboring rows.

INPUT

[image: Input table screenshot]

EXPECTED OUTPUT

[image]

The logic is that since "abc" is connected to "abcd" in the first row and "abcd" is connected to "abcde" in the second row and so on, thus "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdef" are connected and put in one array. The same applied to the rest rows. The number of connected neighboring rows are arbitrary.

The question is how to do that using Hive script without any UDF. Do I have to use Spark for this type of operation? Thanks very much.

One idea I had is to tag rows first as

[image]

How to do that using Hive script only?

Comment: Get any further?

Comment: See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a CONNECT BY query which is *not* supported in HIVE or SPARK, unlike DB2 or ORACLE, et al.

You can simulate such a query with Spark Scala, but it is far from handy. Putting a tag in means the question is less relevant then, imo.

Comment: Any suggestions of how to "putting a tag in" using Hive? I can use it as an intermediate step to achieve the goal. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking up another thing. It looks graphx but not really. Let me get back to you soon.

Comment: http://sqlandhadoop.com/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark/

Comment: This worked in the past, but is cumbersome. Hive, not so sure as non-procedural.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will take a look.

Comment: One day these things will be there.

Comment: yeah, you bet:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work-around using Hive script to get the intermediate table.

```
drop table if exists step1;
create table step1 STORED as orc as 
with src as 
(
select split(u.tmp,",")[0] as node_1, split(u.tmp,",")[1] as node_2
  from
      (select stack (7,
                     "abc,abcd",
                     "abcd,abcde",
                     "abcde,abcdef",
                     "bcd,bcde",
                     "bcde,bcdef",
                     "cdef,cdefg",
                     "def,defg" 
                     ) as tmp 
      ) u 
)
select node_1,  node_2, if(node_2 = lead(node_1, 1) over (order by node_1), 1, 0) as tag, row_number() OVER (order by node_1) as row_num 
from src;


drop table if exists step2;
create table step2 STORED as orc as 
SELECT tag, row_number() over (ORDER BY tag) as row_num 
FROM (
    SELECT cast(v.tag as int) as tag 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        split(regexp_replace(repeat(concat(cast(key as string), ","), end_idx-start_idx), ",$",""), ",") as tags --repeat the row number by the number of rows
        FROM (
            SELECT COALESCE(lag(row_num, 1) over(ORDER BY row_num), 0) as start_idx, row_num as end_idx, row_number() over (ORDER BY row_num) as key
            FROM step1 where tag=0
            ) a 
        ) b 
LATERAL VIEW explode(tags) v as tag
) c ; 


drop table if exists step3; 
create table step3 STORED as orc as 
SELECT 
a.node_1, a.node_2, b.tag 
FROM step1 a 
JOIN step2 b 
ON a.row_num=b.row_num;
```

The final table looks like

```
select * from step3;
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| step3.node_1  | step3.node_2  | step3.tag  |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
| abc           | abcd          | 1          |
| abcd          | abcde         | 1          |
| abcde         | abcdef        | 1          |
| bcd           | bcde          | 2          |
| bcde          | bcdef         | 2          |
| cdef          | cdefg         | 3          |
| def           | defg          | 4          |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

The third column can be used to collect node pairs.